# Correct use of word "Proficiency"

Tags: word-usage

Can the word 'Proficiency' be used for non-living objects like Machinery,etc.?

Comment: How would you use *proficiency* in that way? Please provide a sample sentence, with details of why you feel *proficiency* is wrong -- so that it doesn't become mere prooreading.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you were figuratively personifying the machine somehow.  Otherwise, no, because a machine cannot be in possession of skills or aptitudes.  Depending on what you meant, you would instead use "efficiency" or "effectiveness."

Comment: "Maintaining the Proficiency of assets and property like machines."

Is this acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be used. Take a look at the following example:

> ... is a reflection of the culture's ambivalent fascination with technology, which simultaneously fetishizes and fears the **proficiency** of machines and their ability to replace human effort.

However, it's better to use **capability** for objects.

E.g.

> By the experiments analysis, it can be known that the cutting **capability** of tools were determind by toughness of tools when the hardness of deposited materials

Comment: I'm not convinced your first example uses the word proficiency correctly.  I say that I'm not sure because the context isn't clear.  It doesn't appear to be used in narrative but in some kind of list that may or may not pertain to a person, which proficiency is a human trait, or possibly an animal trait, not an inanimate trait.

Comment: OK, another example added.